# Copy file that is updated every 15 minutes

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have an client the writes a file with data every 15 min. The name of the file is the date of that day.

So in the folder I can have for example:

```
2015-06-01.csv
2015-06-02.csv
2015-06-03.csv
```

What I want is that is to run a script every 15 minutes or if it’s possible to loop the script to see file changes.

I have been looking around an found one script that might work. But don’t get the copy file to work.
I only want to copy the file that’s been change last.

```vb
Option Explicit  
Dim fso, path, file, recentDate, recentFile, filePath

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set recentFile = Nothing
For Each file in fso.GetFolder("C:\CSV\Test\CSVOriginal").Files
  If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
    Set recentFile = file
  ElseIf (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
    Set recentFile = file
  End If
Next

If recentFile is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo "no recent files"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Recent file is " & recentFile.Name & " " & recentFile.DateLastModified
  filePath = fso.GetFile(recentFile.Name)
  WScript.Echo "Recent file is " & filepath
  fso.CopyFile "C:\CSV\Test\CSVOriginal" +recentFile.Name,"C:\CSV\Test\CSVFlytt\"
End If
```

Comment: You want to copy the most-recent file to some other folder every 15 minutes? Or you want to check every 15 minutes to see if a *new* file appears and then copy it to some other folder?

Comment: If you want to copy every generation of a file that's modified every 15 minutes, do you want to keep different generations? Or do you want to replace the previous version?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Loop through your folder to find the most-recently-modified file:

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objFile, strNewestFile, dtmMax
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder("C:\CSV\Test\CSVOriginal").Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > dtmMax Then
        dtmMax = objFile.DateLastModified
        strNewestFile = objFile.Path
    End If
Next

objFSO.GetFile(strNewestFile).Copy "C:\CSV\Test\CSVFlytt\"
```

Comment: Hello i want to copy the most recent file every 15 minutes, and i don’t want to keep the old generation of the file. The script worked great. Thank you allot.